# Get only property value of an element using map function

Tags: javascript

I was trying to get the property value only using a map function. I know If I use map then its going to return an array of elements. So, here is what I am trying to do.

I have this array, of object

```
mainarray = [{ foo : '1' , id:'2' }, { foo : '2' , id:'3' },{ foo : '1' , id:'4' }];
```

Now, here what I am doing is (data is some different array).

```
let count;
if (data) {
    if ((data[0].foo) && (data[0].foo)) {
        count = this.state.mainarray.map((object, index) => {
            if ((object.Id === data[0].id) && (data[0].foo === object.foo)) {
                return object;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have done like this. Now here, if it did not match anything then it returns an array with all `undefined` values, as many elements are there in that.

`[undefined,undefined]`

But I actually tried with `object.foo`, so it should return only that value, But it is not returning. So, I'am stuck over here. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: afaik the native `map` method is only for arrays. you might want consider lodash map or Object.keys() iteration.

Comment: Desired output is only the foo value 1. Because I am matching  if id is 2 then return the value of the key foo

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `filter` method

```
let count;
if (data) {
    if ((data[0].foo) && (data[0].foo)) {
        count = this.state.mainarray.filter((object) => (object.Id === data[0].id) && (data[0].foo === object.foo)).length;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i am not getting the value of that property

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead, and if a match was found you can use that object's `foo` value.

**Example**

```js
const mainarray = [
  { foo: "1", id: "2" },
  { foo: "2", id: "3" },
  { foo: "1", id: "4" }
];
const idToFind = "3";

const obj = mainarray.find(element => element.id === idToFind);
const count = (obj && obj.foo) || "0";

console.log(count);
```